# Commit failed error when committing new version to svn repository

Tags: svn, repository, commit

I'm trying to commit a new version to my SVN repository but am met with this error:

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
>   svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
>   new-computers-computer:trunk newcomputer$

What's wrong?

Comment: @Ether, that error message means nothing if you're new to SVN or the command line. Check out the accepted answer by Blackcoat to see a helpful answer.

Comment: export SVN_EDITOR=vi

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Justin,

Every time you commit with Subversion, you need to write a summary of what is being committed (i.e. the commit message). The error is because Subversion is trying to launch a text editor so that you can write a commit message, but the editor is never being launched. Setting the `SVN_EDITOR` in your .bash_profile will do the trick. Here are some detailed step-by-step instructions on how to set vim as the default editor used by svn: [Original link dead, replaced with archive.is mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210045755/http://www.antbrown.com/web-development/svn-could-not-use-external-editor-to-fetch-log-message)

Alternatively, as suggested in error message, you can load a commit message from an existing file with `-f`, or pass in a message with `-m`.

Examples:

```
svn commit -m "Fixed a regression that prevented pigs from flying (resolves issue #123, but causes strange behavior elsewhere)"
svn commit -f /path/to/a/file/with/a/long/commit/message.txt
```

Comment: In your .bash_profile, add:  export EDITOR="$HOME/bin/mate -w"

Comment: Similarly, you can set Sublime as your default by doing `export EDITOR='subl -w'`. For full details on command line setup for Sublime, see http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

Comment: Message with `-m` will resolve the problem. `svn delete my/branch/path -m "type your message here"` this is the branch delete command with message.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to set default editor that will be used every time you run

```
svn commit
```

Try the following command in the shell:

```
export SVN_EDITOR=nano
```

This will set nano as the text editor for commit messages. From now on, when you call `svn commit` without the `-m` flag, nano will open. Upon closing nano, SVN will continue to commit.

Comment: And what will happen? Please consider to add a description to your answer.

Comment: basically when you need to set default editor, you should use command from above.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue, however it was on Windows. I was able to resolve the issue by using -m (--message) and providing the commit message.

I also tried using cygwin with a commit message and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while trying to import a not versioned code into a new repository, based on the answers posted on this question i was able to solve my problem (thank you guys).

I am sharing the command i used to import a local project to SVN on using apache/http:

Where TestCodeDir is the project and hasn't been versioned yet.

```
svn import /var/svn/TestCodeDir http://localhost/svn/TestCodeDir -m "Initial Commit"
```

Note: You must to have your apache server well configured and it must to be running.

I hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while doing:

```
svn copy $svn_source_path $svn_destination_path
```

I was missing adding the -m "log msg" i.e.

```
svn copy $svn_source_path $svn_destination_path -m -m "Test tag creation"
```