# svn command will not execute due to missing message?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, branch

I'm trying to create a new directory in the branch of my SVN repository as per instructions at http://dryice.name/blog/freebsd/svn-make-the-branches-directory-before-make-a-branch/.

```
svn mkdir http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches \ -m "make the branches directory to hold all the branches"
```

But I get the error:

```
svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```

I saw this question: [Commit failed error when committing new version to svn repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903037/commit-failed-error-when-committing-new-version-to-svn-repository) and I did add the `-m` option with a message but still getting the above error.

What's wrong with the command and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well turns out that if I reverse the order and add my `-m` options first, it works!

So the command should be:

```
svn -m "make the branches directory to hold all the branches" http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches
```